Flutter Invalid Constant value
i am making a ble-scanner and i need to send a ScanResult to another page. i am using parameters. but i get Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
ScanResult result
Type: ScanResult
ScanPage.dart
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:ble/pages/devicePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

bool isRunning = false;

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  void runScan() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.bluetooth,
      Permission.bluetoothScan,
      Permission.bluetoothConnect,
      Permission.location,
      Permission.bluetoothAdvertise
    ].request();

    bool allGranted = statuses.values.every((status) => status.isGranted);

    if (allGranted) {
      _scan();
    } else {
      print("Permissions not granted");
    }
  }

  Future _scan() async {
    FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(days: 14));
    bool isFound = false;
    isRunning = true;
    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((res) {
      if (!isFound) {
        for (ScanResult result in res) {
          if (result.device.id.toString() == "10:CE:A9:0C:7F:C4") {
            isFound = true;
            flutterBlue.stopScan();
            isRunning = false;
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const Devicepage(device: result)));
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    runScan();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("asd"), centerTitle: true),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          new SizedBox(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (!isRunning) runScan();
              },
              child: Text("scan"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}


devicePage.dart
import 'package:ble/pages/ScanPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class Devicepage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScanResult device;
  const Devicepage({super.key, required this.device});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(device.device.name),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}


i want to be able to pass the ScanResult to the devicePage.dart
All help would be appreciated i am a beginner.

In Flutter, you cannot pass an instance like ScanResult directly as a constant in the MaterialPageRoute constructor because the const keyword is used for compile-time constants, and ScanResult is not a compile-time constant.
You should remove the const keyword from the Devicepage constructor call in ScanPage.dart to fix this issue. Here's how you can do it
import 'package:ble/pages/devicePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

bool isRunning = false;

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  void runScan() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.bluetooth,
      Permission.bluetoothScan,
      Permission.bluetoothConnect,
      Permission.location,
      Permission.bluetoothAdvertise
    ].request();

    bool allGranted = statuses.values.every((status) => status.isGranted);

    if (allGranted) {
      _scan();
    } else {
      print("Permissions not granted");
    }
  }

  Future _scan() async {
    FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(days: 14));
    bool isFound = false;
    isRunning = true;
    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((res) {
      if (!isFound) {
        for (ScanResult result in res) {
          if (result.device.id.toString() == "10:CE:A9:0C:7F:C4") {
            isFound = true;
            flutterBlue.stopScan();
            isRunning = false;
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Devicepage(device: result),
              ),
            );
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    runScan();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Scan Page"), centerTitle: true),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (!isRunning) runScan();
              },
              child: Text("Scan"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

you also need to Ensure that Devicepage does not use the const keyword for its constructor
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class Devicepage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScanResult device;
  const Devicepage({super.key, required this.device});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(device.device.name),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Device ID: ${device.device.id}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

best of luck buddy :)

Thank you so much! i don't think i would have ever thought of that! i am pretty new to flutter and i have just got a ble module that i want to create an app for.

this is just beginning buddy, we are future ;)
